# How to extract value of json object key, value pairs using json-c

Tags: c, json

I'm trying to use this function, as the only example I've been able to find is a deprecated version of this function, which has two parameters.
The newer function has three, but when I try to run compile, I get the error:  dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
deprecated function : `*jobj = json_object_object_get(jobj,key)`
new function : `*jobj = json_object_object_get_ex(jobj,key,value)`

I've just tried the following :
json_object_get_string(json_object_object_get(new_obj, "foo"))

But I'm getting the error message that this is deprecated. If I used the newer function, I need to know 'value'. But that's the point, I only know the key and I want to extract the value. Any help would be appreciated as I haven't been able to find any examples other than the above

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if you still need this, but the documentation matches the error you're getting.  The `json_object_object_get()` function is deprecated in favor of `json_object_object_get_ex()`.

Look more closely at the function parameters:

```
json_bool json_object_object_get_ex (struct json_object *obj, const char *key,
struct json_object **value)
```

The `value` parameter is for output, not input.  You supply the address of (or a pointer to) a `json_object*`, and the function fills it in with the return value.  For example:

```
json_object* f(json_object* rootObj, const char* key)
{
    json_object* returnObj;
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(rootObj, key, &returnObj)
    {
        return returnObj;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Source: [json-c API Documentation](http://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.11/doc/html/json__object_8h.html#af3f38b3395b1af8e9d3ac73818c3a936)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up giving up on this (project with a friend), and have been learning Java since (my grad school IT course only offered c++) with a view to becoming a Java developer instead, now that I've graduated ;)